# скриншот экрана с html2canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, screenshots, html2canvas

Проблема в том, что html2canvas делает скриншот всего селектора (в данном случа это body), который указан. А как сделать так, чтобы был только скриншот той части страницы, которая видна экране?
Если указать ширину и высоту, соответствующую размеру экрана, то получается скриншот верхней части страницы, размером с экран. 
Надеюсь, что понятно изложил суть проблемы. Хелп :)

```
$("#scrShot").click(function(){
  html2canvas($("body"), {
    //width: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    //height: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var myImage = canvas.toDataURL();
      window.open(myImage);
    }
  });
});
```

P.S. в идеале еще бы этот скриншот сразу открыть в canvas для редактирования. Но это пока второстепенно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, разобрался.
В новой версии html2canvas имеется возможность опционально задать величину прокрутки (y: value), указывающую на смещение по оси Y.
В итоге просто перед выполнением функции нужно получить значение var scrollFromTop = window.pageYOffset, а затем на эту же величину прокрутить экран при выполнении функции:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    width:document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    height: document.documentElement.clientHeight+scrolledFromTop,
    y: scrollFromTop,
        }).then(function(canvas) {
            //некоторый код
});
```